# Angular routerDirection "forward"

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ionic4

I'm trying to create a forward component like in Ionic 4, push a component into the router-outlet without removing the old template and when I go back pop the pushed component template.
here is Ionic like of what I'm trying to do https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav
Now my question: Can I do that just with angular without Ionic, can please anyone explain how does this works?

here is my routes:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'sreach',
    loadChildren: './sreach/sreach.module#SreachPageModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I want to navigate from home to search like ionic forward without overriding the home, just hide it.

Answer (score 0):

use a model instead of routing thats the only way i know of how to do that. also typo in Routes path:'sreach' => path:'search'